# How to list posts from one table and at the same time sum an amount from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all, hope my English isn't too bad..

I have a problem I can't solve. 
The thing is that I am thinking about an order handling system..
What I have so far is a table where every article registrats that belong to an order like  this

Tbl_orderLines
id, prod_week, article_id

Then i also have och table where the amount for each row in tbl_orderLines registrates like this

Tbl_inventory
orderline_id, article_id, amount

Now article_id in both tables are the same (double post) thought it would be easier to do so?
What I want to is the get the available amount of each specific article at a specific time.
So I want to be able to list every row in Tbl_orderLInes and with a join get the amount for every row, but! I also want to get the total amount of a specific article. Therefore, I want to sum the amount column from Tbl_inventory where the article_id is the same as the row from tbl_orderLines.

This is what I've got now
Tbl_orderLines

```
id         prod_week        article_id    
 1           1130              2   
 2           1129              5          
 3           1129              2     
 4           1128              2
```

Tbl_inventory

```
orderLine_id         article_id      amount     
 1                       2               1          
 2                       5               2          
 3                       2               1          
 4                       2               2
```

The result should be something like

```
id         prod_week        article_id      amount     TotalAmount
 1           1130              2               1          4
 2           1129              5               2          2
 3           1129              2               1          3
 4           1128              2               2          2
```

Don't know if its possible to understand my question?
I'm using MSSQL..

Much appreciate any help..

Comment: How do you know what week an entry in `Tbl_inventory` corresponds to?

Comment: Or the table relationships?  You want to see both amount and the sum of amounts on the same result record?  What does the id represent in your result?  I don't think anybody can help you with a query because their seems to be fundamental issues with your proposed data model.

Comment: The id in tbl_orderLines are in relation with orderLine_id in tbl_inventory. 
The relationship is as above so in tbl_orderLInes i have information about the week and so on and in tbl_inventory the amount of each article is saved. So with a join i can get prod_week and the amount but i also want a Sum of all rows in tbl_inventory where article_id is the same..

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first part of your result set is achieve by the following.

```
SELECT
  [order_line].id,
  [order_line].prod_week,
  [order_line].article_id,
  [inventory].amount
FROM
  Tbl_orderLines             AS [order_line]
INNER JOIN
  Tbl_inventory              AS [inventory]
    ON [inventory].orderline_id = [order_line].id
```

I'm not 100% certain about the TotalAmount column, however.  My best guess is that you want...The sum of the amounts for all preceeding weeks with the same article_id?

```
SELECT
  [order_line].id,
  [order_line].prod_week,
  [order_line].article_id,
  [inventory].amount,
  SUM([historic_inventory].amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM
  Tbl_orderLines             AS [order_line]
INNER JOIN
  Tbl_inventory              AS [inventory]
    ON [inventory].orderline_id = [order_line].id
INNER JOIN
  Tbl_orderLines             AS [historic_orders]
    ON [historic_orders].article_id = [order_line].article_id
    AND[historic_orders].prod_week <= [order_line].prod_week
INNER JOIN
  Tbl_inventory              AS [historic_inventory]
    ON [historic_inventory].orderline_id = [historic_order_line].id
GROUP BY
  [order_line].id,
  [order_line].prod_week,
  [order_line].article_id,
  [inventory].amount
```

Comment: Ummmmm, I don't know, you'll have to tell me.  Your question didn't seem to state exactly what you wanted, this is an answer based on my inferences.  I would suggest trying it against sample data to see if it yields the results you want.

Comment: What i want is to get the sum of the amounts for all preceeding weeks with the same article_id.. I'm about to set upp some sample  data to try your exempel..
Many thanks

Comment: I tried with some sample an your example above works fine execpt for one thing.. 
If theres one article for week "1131" with the amount of 1, and there's the same article for week "1130" with the amount of 3 then the totalAmount for week 1130 is 4 and for week 1131 it is 3. The right result would be an totalAmount for week 1130 of 3 and for week 1131 if would be 4.. seems like it sums it up in the wrong direction....

Comment: Found it! ;) Just changed the following: AND[historic_orders].prod_week >= [order_line].prod_week 

Big thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't get exactly what you want but I believe you can try something like this enhance the idea towards your goal.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inventory](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [article_id] [int] NULL,
    [amount] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orderLines](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [prod_week] [int] NULL,
    [article_id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SELECT ol.id, 
       ol.prod_week, 
       ol.article_id, 
       i.amount, 
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY i.article_id) AS totalAmount
  FROM dbo.orderLines AS ol, dbo.inventory AS i
 WHERE ol.id = i.id
 ORDER BY ol.id
```

Comment: thats amazing, just what i wanted. I really dont understand the code, but still... Now i just want to add Condition the gets the total amount it Sum's all post eralier then prod_week so it would somting like: WHERE prod_week >= prod_week ? 
Thats sounds strange know when i read it, am i thinking right??

Comment: Yes, you can add any condition. OVER and PARTITION clauses are SQL Server extensions to ANSI SQL. There are other ranking and aggregate functions that SQL Server provides. Here's the link; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: Alright, great..
I tried but idont understand where to insert the condition that i only want the sum of all preceeding weeks with the same article_id?

Comment: I don't think you can add a condition to the OVER clause to achieve what the OP is asking for (If I'm wrong I'd love to know how, it sounds very powerful!)

Comment: No, not on OVER clause... You can obviously add any filter criteria on WHERE clause.